# Select from second MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, select, export

I would like to select data from a second MySQL database in order to migrate data from one server to another.

I'm looking for syntax like
SELECT * FROM username:password@serverip.databaseName.tableName

Is this possible? I would be able to do this in Microsoft SQL Server using linked servers, so I'm assuming it's possible in MySQL as well.

Comment: Do you want to migrate all of the data, or just a subset?

Comment: Nope, I don't think this is possible in mySQL. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008208/mysql-import-export) is  one similarly simple approach but it requires console access on one machine, and SSH access on the other.

Comment: I want to migrate all of the data, but the schema has changed between the two servers, so I'd like to do it all in a SELECT statement if possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a table using `FEDERATED` storage engine:

```
CREATE TABLE tableName (id INT NOT NULL, …)
ENGINE=FEDERATED
CONNECTION='mysql://username:password@serverip/databaseName/tableName'

SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
```

Basically, it will serve as a view over the remote `tableName`.

Answer (score 0):

There are generally two approaches you can take, although neither of them sound like what you're after:

1. Use [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html) and set up a master/slave relationship between the two databases.
2. Simply dump the data (using the command line [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html) tool) from the 1st database and import it into the 2nd.

However, both of these will ultimately migrate all of the data (i.e.: not a subset), although you can specify specific table(s) via mysqldump. Additionally, if you use the mysqldump approach and you're not using InnoDB you'll need to ensure that the source database isn't in use (i.e.: has integrity) when the dump is created.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly, but as someone else alluded to in a comment, you can use `mysqldump` to export the contents of a table as a SQL script.

At that point you could run the script on the new server to create the table, or if more manipulation of the data is required, import that data into a table with a different name on the new server, then write a query to copy the data from there.